# Intellij maven window missing

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My Intellij, 2020.1, and also till today 2019.3 has something weird with supporting maven.

Although I can create a new maven project, and get the maven tools window to be available at that project - some of my work related projects, fail to have maven tools enabled.

More details:

These projects have pom.xml at their root (I opened them from root).
I am able to build these projects with command line mvn install.
in Preferences > plugins: Maven is enabled.
in Preferences > build tools > the configuration is like in the picture I attached.
local maven reposistory is where I supplied

[image]

But:

Maven tools window is missing.

In Project structure > Modules > + > I can import all sorts of projects - but not maven.

Classes of maven dependencies appear "red" in the code, and I get no IntelliSense for them.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try reinstalling IntelliJ IDEA from http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html and delete `disabled_plugins.txt` file from the config directory (https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519). If it doesn't help, backup and delete `.idea` directory inside the project and reimport the project by opening the root `pom.xml` file.

Comment: Removing .idea folder did the trick for me - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the project was not associated with Maven. In such cases opening `pom.xml` file explicitly would reimport the project and will fix the problem.

You can also try [adding Maven support to the existing project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/convert-a-regular-project-into-a-maven-project.html).